# Transformer Schematic Explanation

Tags: pcb-design, transformer, power-electronics, poe

Why does this design use two winding secondary outputs? I do not understand what is happening here. I know that the device converts for POE 5V 4.8W, but that secondary winding setup, how could I simplify it to a single secondary winding? Seems like the top circuit nets for NS2 could connect directly to positive voltage output, and the secondary winding output can go to SGND while eliminating the bottom winding NS1.

[image]

Comment: Notice that you have the N channel MOSFET at the "positive rail" (the source at the positive terminal). Thus, to be able to properly turn on the MOSFET the voltage at the gate needs to be higher than the source voltage. So you need to have a voltage higher than the NS1 winding voltage.  And this is the job for NS2 winding.